# Create logic in one controller accessing two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three models, `Artwork`, `ArtworkTag`, and `Tag`, where `ArtworkTag` represents an m:n relation between `Artwork` and `Tag`. `Tag` only stores the tag name, i.e. `:tag`.

When creating tags from `ArtworkTagsController`, it's necessary to first see if the `:tag` exists in the `tags` table, create it if not, and then use the tag `id` to make the relation in `ArtworkTag`.

Below you can see that I'm calling `Tag` directly from this controller, which I don't think is the right practice.

How should I be handling this situation with the proper separation of concerns?

```
def create
  tag = params[:artwork_tag][:tag].downcase
  @tag = Tag.find_by_tag(tag)

  if @tag.blank?
    @tag = Tag.new(:tag => tag)
    @tag.save
  end

  artwork_id = params[:artwork_tag][:artwork_id]
  user_id = params[:artwork_tag][:user_id]

  artwork_tag = {
    "tag_id" => @tag.id,
    "artwork_id" => artwork_id,
    "user_id" => user_id
  }

  @artwork_tag = ArtworkTag.new(:tag_id => @tag.id, :artwork_id => artwork_id, :user_id => user_id)
  @artwork_tag.save
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => {
      "id" => @artwork_tag.id, "tag" => @tag.tag, "artwork_id" => artwork_id },
      :status => :created }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
def create
  artwork_tag = ArtworkTag.create(
    :tag => Tag.find_or_create_by_tag(params[:artwork_tag][:tag].downcase),
    :artwork_id => params[:artwork_tag][:artwork_id],
    :user_id => params[:artwork_tag][:user_id]
  )

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => { :artwork_tag => artwork_tag } }
  end
end
```

Comment: I of course don't have a way to test this, but this should be functionally equivalent to what you have in your question.

Comment: This works fine, although when I add in CanCan's `load_and_authorize_resource` at the top of the controller, I get `ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: tag):`. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah. In `app/models/artwork_tag.rb`, add `attr_accessible :tag` to the top of the model, one like the second line, right after the class definition. You might want to read a little bit about mass assignment since that's probably not the only place you'll have to an an `attr_accessible` in order to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but you can use `first_or_create` method to check if record is already exists or not, if not it will create new record. You can replace this:

```
@tag = Tag.find_by_tag(tag)

if @tag.blank?
  @tag = Tag.new(:tag => tag)
  @tag.save
end
```

with only one row: (I'm not use instance variable because i think you don't need use it in view, if you need just change it to `@tag` and in params to `tag_id: @tag.id`)

```
tag = Tag.where(tag: tag).first_or_create()
```

I see you defined `artwork_tag`, but why you aren't use it? I think you can replace:

```
artwork_tag = {
  "tag_id" => @tag.id,
  "artwork_id" => artwork_id,
  "user_id" => user_id
}

@artwork_tag = ArtworkTag.new(:tag_id => @tag.id, :artwork_id => artwork_id, :user_id => user_id)
@artwork_tag.save
```

with this code:

```
params = { artwork_tag: { 
                          tag_id: tag.id, 
                          artwork_id: artwork_id, 
                          user_id: user_id  } }
@artwork_tag = ArtworkTag.create(params[:artwork_tag])
```